# htaccess need to delete page.php?url=

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a slider in the PHP, for example the news articles have this extension by default:

*project_07_news_portal/page?url=altay_tanki_ihalesi_icin_geri_sayim*

I want it to appear like

*project_07_news_portal/altay_tanki_ihalesi_icin_geri_sayim*

I have tried the code below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\page.php?url -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.page.php?url=
```

I get error, Forbidden - You don't have permission to access on this server.

Comment: The requested output does not contain any "page.php", your rules do, how should that work?

Comment: Particularly **[this answer on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108/3536236)**

Comment: @Martin thanks, that answer on that question is very informative